# Handle error 503 in application web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, http-status-code-503

i tried to handle the error code 503
in my application web.xml as follows:

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>503</error-code>
   <location>/serviceNotAvailable</location>
   </error-page>
```

but it's not working i don't know why, please advise.
i am using apache,tomcat.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the server not display **/serviceNotAvailable**? What resource is mapped to **/serviceNotAvailable**, a servlet, jsp, etc.?

Comment: when 503 occurs, user is not forwarded to the serviceNotAvailable page, btw /serviceNotAvaiable is a jsp page mapped to a spring controller. and btw too above works fine with error code 400

Comment: how are you testing a 503? overloading your server?

Comment: stopping and starting tomcat quickly without no sleeping time between shutdown and start

Comment: but if you shut down your tomcat, then who will serve the /serviceNotAvailable page? It wont work at all. and if tomcat is running up does the logs show a 503 occured or you get on browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in similar situation and end up using apache in front of tomcat.

Ie when tomcat is down from some reason, Apache intercept the 503, and use httpd config

```
Error Document 503
```

to redirect to your own custom page. Some details can be found here [apache tomcat 503 custom error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666704/apache-tomcat-503-custom-error-page).

503 is quite serious compared to 404 etc, most of time there are some un-recoverable error which crash the service/app, in our case heap-memory issues.

I would also be quite interested in anyone else comes up with how to redirect 503 from Tomcat alone.