# How can we redirect login page while tomcat shutdown or restart?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

How can we redirect login page while tomcat shutdown or restart ?

Comment: is the login page part of the webapp in tomcat and does it still need to be working?

Comment: You want a custom maintaince page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666704/apache-tomcat-503-custom-error-page