# Redirect to maintenance.html from apache when tomcat down not working

Tags: apache, web-services, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I have apache setup in front of tomcat using mod_jk.

I have the below configured in my apache config file:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
```

But my site does not redirect to this page if tomcat is down. If I replace with:

```
ErrorDocument 503 "foo"
```

as [suggested in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592848/redirect-tomcat-to-maintenance-page-when-down/24069305#24069305) but it won't display foo. In both cases the page remains fairly blank and a banner pops up saying 503. If I open chrome tools and look on the network tab I get this:

[image]

where /current returns 503. The console tab shows 503 errors also. I am not a developer so handle the apache/tomcat config so I assume this problem needs fixing on my side - although could be wrong.

Thanks

edit: jkmount and errorducument entries below:

```
        JkMount /* loadbalancer
        JkMount /*.html loadbalancer
        JkUnMount / loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /index.html loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /assets/* loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /favicon.ico loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /icon/* loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /image/* loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /jar/*.jar loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /maintenance.html loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /pdf/*.pdf loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /policy/*.html loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /resources/* loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /zip/*.zip loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.css loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.jpg loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.js loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.ttf loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.woff loadbalancer
        JkUnMount /*.woff2 loadbalancer

        ErrorDocument 400 /error/
                # Unauthorized (i.e. HTTP authentication required)
        ErrorDocument 401 /error/
                # Forbidden
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/
                # Not Found
        ErrorDocument 404 /error/
                # Method Not Allowed
        ErrorDocument 405 /error/
                # Request URI Too Long
        ErrorDocument 414 /error/
                # Internal Server Error
        ErrorDocument 500 /error/
                # Not Implemented
        ErrorDocument 501 /error/
                # Service Not Available
        ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
                # HTTP Version Not Supported
        ErrorDocument 510 /error/
```

Comment: Hi there - don't want to share the whole files as it contains information relative to our project. Is there any particular part you want to know?

Comment: I want to check  JKMount and ErroDocument Entry.

Comment: sure put in the main post thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below configuration and test.

```
ErrorDocument 503 "foo"
JkMount /* loadbalancer;use_server_errors=503
JkMount /*.html loadbalancer;use_server_errors=503
```

Use ErrorDocument before JkMount.

Comment: So I tried that but it wasn't working. Just to clarify do I remove the current jkmount values or keep them in when trying this?

Comment: Share your latest JkMount and ErrorDocument entry.

Comment: To test I just removed the 2 JKMount lines in my config and pasted your 3 lines in there instead

Comment: Please share worker.list entry from worker.properties file.Have you restarted httpd after suggested changes? This configuration works fine at my end.I think some mismatch confguration in your files.

Comment: Yes have restarted apache. And "worker.list=loadbalancer"

Comment: Remove all JkUnMount entry and test.Looks like `JkUnMount / loadbalancer` is culprit.

Comment: brilliant removing the JkUnMount worked - you mind explaining why? Any knowledge of why it would be there in the first place?

Comment: `JkUnMount / loadbalancer` this disabled all mod_jk mount. That why it is searching for default httpd index.html.

Comment: I can't see how it would have disabled all of mod_jk mount as tomcat was working as expected other than that. Either way thanks so much for the help